# Website Images not indexed by Google, Yahoo and Bing

Tags: image, apache, header, seo

My classifieds website has been present online since 2006, the html pages are indexed and rank as expected whereas a search on Google Images for **site:example.com** returns nothing & in Yahoo or Bing it returns only a few image results, 8 to 10.

Here is an example of a response HTTP headers as reported by Firebug:

```
Date                 Sat, 15 Jan 2011 20:38:21 GMT
Server               Apache
Cache-Control        max-age=34560000
Expires              Sun, 19 Feb 2012 20:38:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges        bytes
Last-Modified        Fri, 14 Jan 2011 21:59:16 GMT
Vary                 Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding     gzip
Content-Length       21675
Connection           close
Content-Type         image/jpeg
```

What should I do to tell search engines to index my website images?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example URL of an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some documentation on how to make your images searchable:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=114016

Two important points from the resource is naming conventions for the filenames, such as blue-sky.jpg as opposed to IMGXYZ.jpg, as well as using alt tags properly.

```
 <img alt="Blue Sky in Montana" src="/images/blue-sky.jpg" />
```

Note that a dash is read as a space by most search engines in a URL.

**UPDATE: Here is a snippet directly from Google's Support site:**

The filename can give Google clues about the subject matter of the image. Try to make your filename a good description of the subject matter of the image. For example, my-new-black-kitten.jpg is a lot more informative than IMG00023.JPG. Descriptive filenames can also be useful to users: If we're unable to find suitable text in the page on which we found the image, we'll use the filename as the image's snippet in our search results.

Comment: The img tags on the website look like <img height="450" width="600" alt="olive oil" src="/images/ads/129432090903.jpg">, while a user uploads an image I replace the name with the upload time timestamp plus 2 random numbers, I think that a name like 129432090903.jpg won't intimidate Google... Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Nabil - According to Google, a name like 12943 yada yada yada tells them absolutely nothing about the image.  Unless people are searching for the images by the number, they're less likely to be found when there are more relevant, and appropriately named, images out there to show as results instead.

Comment: [`alt`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-alt) is an [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) and not a [tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [image sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636) on you site? It is suggested way by Google for image indexation.

Comment: Never heard of that.. Thanks!

Comment: I will consider this solution too. Thanks